# GCE Network Load Balancing

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two websites functioning under Google Compute Engine VM instances. Both sites accept requests and communicate only via HTTPS and not on HTTP.

How can I properly set a Network Load Balancer forwarding rule under GCE for HTTPS? I have my forwarding rule set on both port 80/443 (HTTP/HTTPS) but my health check always shows unhealthy. It seems like it can't handle HTTPS forwarding.

The way I have my site only doing HTTPS is by having a mod header loaded in Apache and strict transport security enabled. I then have a rewrite rule from HTTP to HTTPS for all requests.

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks),

> There are two types of health checks available:
>
> HTTP health checks, which are required for HTTP and network load
>   balancing.
>
> HTTPS health checks, which are required when setting up
>   backend services to use HTTPS.

Therefore, a network load balancer uses an HTTP health check and it can't handle HTTPS forwarding. You'll need to setup a website, at least for the health check, that allows HTTP and returns an HTTP response with code 200.

Comment: Or use the HTTPS healtcheck! +1

Comment: @aqquadro and how would I use the HTTPS healthcheck? I can't seem to figure out how to do the HTTPS healthcheck. I can only get an HTTP healthcheck to work. I don't see an option for HTTPS

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#updating_health_checks there are two tabs of sample HTTP and HTTPS :P

Comment: Have you currently tried it? HTTPS health checks are currently alpha and not public widely available. For Network load balancing, a regular HTTP health check must be configured and the HTTP servers must reply with a 200 OK code to them when the servers are running fine. The health check URL must be customized for achieve this.

Comment: @Adrian, I get it now. So HTTPS isn't for networking load balancing. Soon they'll have it but it's Alpha at the moment. With that said, I took your advice and created a web page specifically for the health check. Thank you!